# SqlDataAdapter, stored procedures and parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I have a few questions regarding stored procs and the `SqlDataAdapter`:

When I run the adapter's `Update` method, I understand it will call the specified `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` commands where appropriate, based on the `RowState` property of the table's rows.

- If these commands are set to stored procedures, does it pass parameters for each column in the table with the correct values, or does it pass the table row in question?
- Do you have to specify all parameters manually, or does the adapter know which values to pass?
- Is it possible to make a sp for, let's say Insert, without defining parameters for each column?
- If you pass the table row the sp should know both column names and values (or not)?

What I actually try to achieve, is to have one `INSERT`, one `UPDATE` and one `DELETE` stored proc to work on all tables in my database. From wherever in my app where I have to do some data handling, I would call a data handler to prepare necessary parameters and values before running `adapter.Update()`.

Impossible, bad approach or brilliant?

Comment: Show your code What you have tried so far.

Comment: `"have one Insert-, one Update- and one Delete-stored proc"` to handle all tables sounds like a bad idea in my opinion. How do you intend to handle relational data in a generic method. I assume you will have business logic specific to each entity so you will get in to the realm of, if it's this table do this and if it's that table do something else. I'd keep them all separate and logical.

Comment: Sounds like a **horribly bad design** to me. One stored procedure to handle all `INSERT` for all tables? Good luck! That'll be **one HUGE mess** of code to handle all cases, and think about the **maintenance nightmare** if you have to add two, five, twenty new tables..... you should look into the **Single Responsibility Principle** - each piece of code should do **one thing and ONE thing ONLY**.

Comment: Would it, really? I can't see which 'cases' this could be. In my DataHandler I would prepare the data regardless of which table it origins from, to a certain standard and perform an insert or update. I can see a huge mess if I have to have four stored procs for each table (and I have 150 of them). Maybe I am not aware of all pitfalls...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on number of columns in your tables, you can have even one stored procedure to add, update or delete from your database. It seems to be a bad idea if you have a big variety of column numbers.
Anyways, You can use dynamic SQL to pass the table names, but you should be aware of SQL injection risks, especially if your project is a web app.